# OpenGL pass integer array with GL_ARRAY_BUFFER

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, game-engine

I am trying to pass some integer values to the Vertex Shader along with the vertex data.

I generate a buffer while vertex array is bound and then try to attach it to a location but it seems like in vertex shader the value is always 0.

here is part of the code that generates the buffer and it`s usage in the shader.

```
glm::vec3 materialStuff = glm::vec3(31, 32, 33);

glGenBuffers(1, &materialBufferIndex);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, materialBufferIndex);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec3), &materialStuff, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(9);
glVertexAttribIPointer(9, 3, GL_INT, sizeof(glm::vec3), (void*)0);
```

And here is part of the shader that suppose to receive the integer values

```
// Some other locations
layout (location = 0) in vec3 vertex_position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 vertex_texcoord;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 vertex_normal;
layout (location = 3) in vec3 vertex_tangent;
layout (location = 4) in vec3 vertex_bitangent;
layout (location = 5) in mat4 vertex_modelMatrix;
// layout (location = 6) in_use...
// layout (location = 7) in_use...
// layout (location = 8) in_use...

// The location I am attaching my integer buffer to
layout (location = 9) in ivec3 vertex_material;
// I also tried with these variations
//layout (location = 9) in int vertex_material[3];
//layout (location = 9) in int[3] vertex_material;

// and then in vertex shader I try to retrieve the int value by doing something like this
diffuseTextureInd = vertex_material[0];
```

That diffuseTextureInd should go to fragment shader through

```
out flat int diffuseTextureInd;
```

And I am planning to use this to index into an array of bindless textures that I already have set up and working. The issue is that it seems like vertex_material just contains 0`s since my fragment shader always displays the 0`th texture in the array.

Note: I know that my fragment shader is fine since if I do

```
diffuseTextureInd = 31;
```

in the vertex shader, the fragment shader correctly receives the correct index and displays the correct texture. But when I try to use the value from the layout location 9, it seems like I always get a 0. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Your `materialStuff` in sample code defines just a single triplet (for a single triangle it should be at least array of 3 vec3). Are you drawing point sprites?

Comment: You are using `glm::vec3` which are float vectors. Thus your buffer also contains float data. You can't simply attach that to a integer parameter since a float and a int are not binary compatible. Use `glm::ivec3` if you want integers.

Comment: So I did try it with ivec3 as well and the result was the same. What worked, for now, is passing this data not once per object but for each vertex. It seems wasteful though because I need to attach like 6 bytes of data (for 3 textures) to each vertex. Any good way of handling that issue?

Comment: So do you have 3 integer indices per vertex or 1? Why 6 bytes (`3*sizeof(int) = 4`)?

Answer (score 0):

The following definitions:

```cpp
glm::vec3 materialStuff = glm::vec3(31, 32, 33);
glVertexAttribIPointer(9, 3, GL_INT, sizeof(glm::vec3), (void*)0);
```

...

```c
layout (location = 9) in ivec3 vertex_material;
```

practically mean that:

- `glm::vec3` means that you declare vector of 3 floats rather than integers. `glm::ivec3` should be used for vector of integer.
- `ivec3` vertex attribute means a vector of 3 integer values is expected for each vertex. At the same moment, `materialStuff` defines values only for a single vertex (makes no sense for a triangle, which would require at least 3 `glm::ivec3`).

What is supposed to be declared for passing a single integer vertex attribute:

- `layout (location = 9) in int vertex_material;`
  (without any array qualifier)
- `GLint materialStuff[3] = { 31, 32, 33 };`
- `glVertexAttribIPointer(9, 1, GL_INT, sizeof(GLint)*3, (void*)0);`

It should be noticed though, that passing different per-vertex integer to fragment shader makes no sense, which I suppose you solved by [flat](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Interpolation_qualifiers) keyword. Existing pipeline defines only per-vertex inputs, not per-triangle or something like this. There are [glVertexAttribDivisor()](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribDivisor.xhtml) defining the vertex attribute rate, but it is applicable only to rendering instances via [glDrawArraysInstanced()](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawArraysInstanced.xhtml)/[glDrawElementsInstanced()](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawElementsInstanced.xhtml) (specific vertex attribute might be increment per instance), not triangles.

There are ways to handle per-triangle inputs - this could be done by defining Uniform Buffer Object or [Texture Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Texture) (same as 1D texture but for accessing by index without interpolation) instead of generic Vertex Attribute. But tricks will be still necessary to determine the triangle index in this array - again, from vertex attribute or from built-in variables like [gl_VertexID](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_VertexID.xhtml) in Vertex Shader, [gl_PrimitiveIDIn](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_PrimitiveIDIn.xhtml) in Geometry Shader or [gl_PrimitiveID](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_PrimitiveID.xhtml) in Fragment Shader (I cannot say, though, how these counters are affected by culling).